# How can I output my webcam directly to a simple HTML page?

Tags: html, webcam

I have a webcam server portforwarded by my router so I can access it from a webpage with

```
router-ip:port-number
```

I can access this in Firefox, but other browsers get confused by entering the ip directly in the URI bar as they try to resolve the domain name.

So what simple code can I use to embed the webcam in a webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="http://ip-address:port-number/"/>
```

Here's how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Mozilla's tutorial [Taking webcam photos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/taking_webcam_photos). Have a try.

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit long winded for what I want to do though (100 lines of code versus 1 line of code). The code I included works fine. I might like to stream audio in the future, but that's another story.